# R error at startup: evaluation nested too deeply

Tags: r, recursion, startup

[image]

Now this is a first, but when I call base R, it always gives the following error message at startup:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

- It is not an RStudio error, as it pops up in cmd R.
- It is not the new version 4.0.0 error, because I've experienced this starting with my trusted 3.6.3---the 4.0.0 was my attempt to see if this would go away with a clean install of a new version.
- I did restart the computer.

I looked up the error messages and they were all related to functions that actually do call loops or similarly---no idea why at startup this error would pop up. And there's no big changes to the environment. Some unrelated programs (webcam programs, for instance) installed.

Any pointers? This is baffling. I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @chinsoon12 I figured it out---I was going through learning `blogdown`, and I accidentally put the

```
if (file.exists('~/.Rprofile')) {
  base::sys.source('~/.Rprofile', envir = environment())
}
```

into my `/.Rprofile`, instead of in `.Rprofile` of the website project. No wonder the recursion.

Comment: Was there something specific that can be done to fix this? It seems to persist even after I re-install R?

Comment: @JamesThomasDurant delete the above lines from your `/.Rprofile` if you have done sth similar to me. If this is not the issue, I suggest you open a new question.

Comment: THANK YOU KIM! The problem was finding the stupid file - it was actually needed to locate it as it was OneDrive for some whacky reason.